# Related Model Column Names in django-datatables-view

Tags: python, django, django-datatable

I'm trying to work with django-datatables-view to add some basic filtering and sorting to my ListView.

I have a `Result` model, which has a FK relationship to a `Test` model. The `Result` model has fields `status` and `when`, and the `Test` has fields 'name', 'pass_percentage', and 'maintained' (these are the only fields I'm interested in displaying, both models have additional fields.

I have the following code:

```
class TestListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model = Result
    columns = ['test__name', 'test__pass_percentage', 'test__maintained', 'status', 'when']
    order_columns = ['test__name', 'test__pass_percentage', 'test__maintained', 'status', 'when']

    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        results = (
            Result.objects.filter(
                canonical=True, environment__config__in=['staging', 'production']
            )
                .select_related('test', 'environment')
                .order_by('test__name', '-created_at')
                .distinct('test__name')
                .exclude(test__name__startswith='e2e')
        )
        #print (results.first()._meta.local_fields)

        return results
```

But when I view the JSON endpoint, only the `status` and `when` fields have values. How should I be passing related model field names to `columns`?